# Why is my left join behaving like an inner join? Join works fine if data is changed

Tags: sql

**Original Data**

| PKG | INDICES |
| --- | --- |
| I17 | 21 |
| I17 | 42 |
| I17 | 76 |
| I17 | BMAA |
| I17 | XW |
| I20 | 21 |
| I20 | 42 |
| I20 | 76 |
| I20 | BMAA |
| I20 | XW |
| I19 | 42 |
| I19 | 76 |
| I19 | XW |

Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM fqipkg2 a
LEFT JOIN fqipkg2 b ON (a.pkg <> b.pkg
                        AND a.indices = b.indices)
WHERE a.pkg = 'i17'
  AND (b.pkg = 'i19'
       OR b.pkg IS NULL)
```

This results in the following output:

| PKG | INDICES | PKG | INDICES |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| I17 | 42 | I19 | 42 |
| I17 | 76 | I19 | 76 |
| I17 | XW | I19 | XW |

The desired output is

| PKG | INDICES | PKG | INDICES |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| I17 | 21 | NULL | NULL |
| I17 | 42 | I19 | 42 |
| I17 | 76 | I19 | 76 |
| I17 | BMAA | NULL | NULL |
| I17 | XW | I19 | XW |

Interestingly, we get the desired output when we change the data set to:

| PKG | INDICES |
| --- | --- |
| I17 | 21 |
| I17 | 42 |
| I17 | 76 |
| I17 | BMAA |
| I17 | XW |
| I19 | 42 |
| I19 | 76 |
| I19 | XW |

Is something wrong with the query? the data? any help appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Move conditions on the left joined table out of the `where` and into the join condition:

```
select * 
from fqipkg2 a
left join fqipkg2 b on a.pkg <> b.pkg
    and a.indices = b.indices
    and (b.pkg = 'i19' or b.pkg is null)
where a.pkg = 'i17'
```

The reason this works is that referencing the joined table in the where clause effectively converts the outer join to an inner join, because `b.pkg` must have a value to make the comparison `b.pkg = 'i19'`, and only *joined* rows have values.

Answer (score 0):

The join does never leaves null indices on either side because you join on them. Look at the join table before the where clause:

```
a.pgk | joined on index | b.pkg
i20 | 21 | i17
i20 | 42 | i17
i20 | 42 | i19
i20 | 76 | i27
i20 | 79 | i19
i20 | BMAA | i17
i20 | XW | i17
i20 | XW | i19
i17 | 21 | i20
i17 | 42 | i20
i17 | 42 | i19   <- where a.pkg = 'i17' and (b.pkg = 'i19' ...)
i17 | 76 | i20 
i17 | 76 | i19   <- where a.pkg = 'i17' and (b.pkg = 'i19' ...)
i17 | MBAA | i20
i17 | XW | i20
i17 | XW | i19   <- where a.pkg = 'i17' and (b.pkg = 'i19' ...)
i19 | 42 | i29
i19 | 42 | i17
i19 | 76 | i20
i19 | 76 | i17
i19 | XW | i20
i19 | XW | i17
```

@Bohemian beat me with coming up a corrected query but I'll leave this here just so you can understand better why the result was what it was.

Comment: Thank you Simo. In this context, why wouldn't the join condition (a.pkg <> b.pkg and a.indices = b.indices) where a.pkg = 'i17' and (b.pkg = 'i19' or b.pkg is null) result in something like this?
i17 | 21 | i20
i17 | 42 | i20
i17 | 76 | i20
i17 | MBAA | i20
i17 | XW | i20
i17 | 42 | i19   <- where a.pkg = 'i17' and (b.pkg = 'i19' ..)
i17 | 76 | i19   <- where a.pkg = 'i17' and (b.pkg = 'i19' ..)
i17 | XW | i19   <- where a.pkg = 'i17' and (b.pkg = 'i19' ..)
i17 | NULL | NULL <- where a.pkg = 'i17' and (b.pkg = 'i19' ..)
i17 | NULL | NULL <- where a.pkg = 'i17' and (b.pkg = 'i19' ..)